# best practice database design for tracking progress through related tables (multiple left joins)

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, left-join

I have a django database application, which is constantly evolving.

We want to track the progress of samples as they progress from

```
sample ->  library -> machine -> statistics, etc.
```

Generally it is a one to many relationship from each stage left to right.

Here is a simplified version of my database schema

```
table sample
id    
name  

table library 
id     
name 
sample_id  (foreign key to sample table) 

table machine 
id
name
status
library_id  (foreign key to library table)

table sample_to_projects 
sample_id
project_id

table library_to_subprojects
library_id 
subproject_id
```

So far it has been going ok, except now, everything needs to be viewed by projects. Each of the stages can belong to one or more projects. I have added a many_to_many relation between project and the existing tables.

I am trying to create some views that do the multiple left joins and show the progress of samples for a project.

```
sample A
sample B   library_1    machine_1   
sample B   library_2    machine_2
sample C   library_3
```

first try at the query was like this:

```
SELECT fields FROM
sample_to_projects , 
sample 
LEFT JOIN library ON sample.id = library.sample_id , 
library_to_project 
LEFT JOIN machine ON machine.library_id = library.id
WHERE 
    sample_to_project.project_id = 30 
    AND sample_to_project.sample_id = sample.id
    AND library_to_project.project_id = 30
    AND library_to_project.library_id = library_id
```

The problem here is that the LEFT JOIN is done before the WHERE clause.

So if we have a sample that belongs to project_A and project_B. 
If the sample has a library for project_B, but we want to filter on project_A, the LEFT JOIN does not add a row with NULLs for library columns (as there are libraries). However these rows get filtered back out by the WHERE clause, and the sample does not show up.

```
reults filtering on project_A

sample_1(project_A, project_B)   library_A (project_A)
sample_1(project_A, project_B)   library_B (project_A, project_B)
sample_2(project_A, project_B)   library_C (project_B)  *this row gets filtered out, it should show only the sample details*
```

So my solution is to create a subquery to join the other (right hand side) tables before the LEFT JOIN is done.

```
SELECT fields FROM
     sample_to_projects , 
     sample 
     LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT library.id as lib_id , library.sample_id as smaple_id ,  library.name as lib_name , machine_name 
          FROM library , 
          lib_to_projects ,  
          machine         
     ) 
     AS join_table ON sample.id = join_table.sample_id 
     WHERE 
         sample_to_project.project_id = 30 
         AND sample_to_project.sample_id = sample.id
```

The problem is that there are a few more stages in the real version of my database, so I will need to do a nested subquery for each LEFT JOIN. The SQL will be getting pretty large ad difficult to read, and I wondered if there is a better solution at the design level? Also it won't play nicely with Django models (though if I can get the SQL working I will be happy enough).

Or can anyone suggest some sort of best practices for this type of problem? I am sure it must be relatively common with showing users in groups or something similar. If anyone knows a way that would fit well with django models that would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating sepatate views for each Project_Id?

If you leave the database structure as is and add to it as the application progresses. You can create a separate view for each stage or Project_Id. If there are 30 stages (Project_Id 1..30) then create 30 separate views.

When you add a new stage... create a new view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not precisely clear on what you're using this for, but it looks like your use-case could benefit from Pivot Tables.  Microsoft Excel and Microsoft Access have these, probably the easiest to set up as well.

Basically, you set up a query that joins all your related data together, possibly with some parameters a user would fill in (would make things faster if you have large amounts of data), then feed the result to the Pivot Table, and then you can group things any way you want.  You could, on the fly, see subprojects by library, samples by machine, libraries by samples, and filter on any of those fields as well.  So you could quickly make a report of Samples by Machine, and filter it so only samples for machine 1 show up.

The benefit is that you make one query that includes all the data you might want, and then you can focus on just arranging the groups and filtering.  There are more heavy-duty systems for this sort of stuff (OLAP servers), but you may not need that if you don't have huge amounts of data.

Comment: Its a Django and MySQL based app. So Microsoft solutions are out.So far doing it at the application level seems easiest.I thought there would be some join syntax I was missing to include nulls from multiple joins rather than discarding the row after the second join (when the second table would be nulls).